# Changing default settings for JMS messaging in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I've found only a way to specify JMS settings directly on end points, but I would like to change default values, so that we do not have to remember to set the same value on each endpoint.

Below there are few examples of properties which I would like to set globally:

1. `from("jms:topic:xyx?concurrentConsumers=1")` I would be good to have an option to set different `concurrentConsumers` value for queues and topics.
2. `from("jms:queue:abc?receiveTimeout=60000&concurrentConsumers=1")`
3. Enable transaction for each JMS Message, so I do not have to call `from(...).transacted()`

Comment: Set the options on the component level - http://camel.apache.org/activemq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always define your components as a bean and reuse them everywhere. In your case, you can have:

```
<bean id="activemq" 
  class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
  <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
  <property name="transacted" value="true"/>
</bean>
```